# Extracting a logarithmic divergence of an expression using Series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion, assumptions

Consider the following expression:

```
expr = ((3 M - r0) (4 Cos[θ]^2 (25 M - 11 r0
          + (-3 M + r0) Cos[2 θ]) EllipticE[(4 (-2 M + r0) Sec[θ]^2)/(3 M - r0)]
          + 4 (-19 M + 9 r0 + (-3 M + r0) Cos[2 θ]) EllipticK[(4 (-2 M + r0) Sec[θ]^2)/(3 M - r0)] Sin[θ]^2)
         )/(4 π r0^3 Sqrt[Cos[θ]^2] (-8 M + 4 r0 + (-3 M + r0) Cos[θ]^2)^2);
```

where $r_0 > 3M > 0$ are some parameters. I know that this expression diverges logarithmically as $\theta \to \pi/2$. One quick way to see this is by picking specific values for $r_0$ and $M$. For example:

```
Series[expr /. r0 -> 4 /. M -> 1, {θ, π/2, 0}, Assumptions -> θ > π/2]
```

I am having a lot of trouble however doing this for general $r_0$ and $M$.
Specifically, simply evaluating

```
Assuming[{θ > π/2, r0 > 3 M > 0}, Simplify[Series[expr, {θ, π/2, 0}]]]
```

and Mathematica has trouble giving me the explicitly expression.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If `Limit[expr, \[Theta] -> Pi/2, Assumptions -> {r0 > 3 M > 0}]` give me: `-\[Infinity]`  and `Series[expr /. r0 -> 4 /. M -> 1, {\[Theta], \[Pi]/2, 0}, 
 Assumptions -> \[Theta] > \[Pi]/2]` give me: `SeriesData[\[Theta], 
 Rational[1, 2]
   Pi, {Rational[1, 2048] Pi^(-1) (
   20 2^Rational[1, 2] - 4 2^Rational[1, 2] Log[
    2] - 2^Rational[1, 2] Log[
    8] + 2 2^Rational[1, 2] Log[
     Rational[-1, 2] Pi + \[Theta]])}, 0, 1, 1]` on Mathematica 13.0.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Hence the logarithmic divergence.

Comment: I'm unsure what you want. How's `Limit[expr/Log[\[Theta] - \[Pi]/2], \[Theta] -> Pi/2, Assumptions -> {r0 > 3 M > 0}]`?

Comment: @MichaelE2 yes that works. For some reason, I convinced myself it did not...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility is to use the new in M12.1 function [`Asymptotic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Asymptotic):

```
asym = Assuming[
    r0 > 3 M > 0 && θ > Pi/2,
    Simplify @ Asymptotic[expr, θ -> Pi/2]
]
Coefficient[asym, Log[θ - Pi/2]] //Simplify
```

> (Sqrt[(3 M - r0)/(
> 2 M - r0)] (28 M - 12 r0 - 12 M Log[2] +
> r0 Log[16] + (-3 M + r0) Log[(8 M - 4 r0)/(
> 3 M - r0)] + (6 M - 2 r0) Log[-(π/2) + θ]))/(8 π (2 M -
> r0) r0^3)

> ((3 M - r0)/(2 M - r0))^(3/2)/(4 π r0^3)

Answer (score 2):

Method 1:

If a function, $f(x)$, is known to have an expansion of the form
$$f(x) = a + b \log(x) + \mathcal{O}(x),$$
then $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}xf'(x)=b$.

So, for my example, first compute the derivative of the expressions:

```
exprD = D[expr, θ] // FullSimplify;
```

Then

```
Assuming[{θ > π/2, r0 > 3 M > 0}, Simplify[Series[exprD (θ - π/2), {θ, π/2, 1}]]]
```

and this extracts the coefficient of the logarithmic term.

Method 2:
as suggested by @MichealE2, simply perform the approriate limit

```
Limit[expr/Log[θ - π/2], θ -> Pi/2, Assumptions -> {r0 > 3 M > 0}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way:

```
Assuming[{θ > π/2, r0 > 3 M > 0}, 
 Simplify@
  CoefficientList[Simplify@Series[expr, {θ, π/2, 1}], 
    Log[-(π/2) + θ]][[2]]
 ]

(*  ((3 M - r0)/(2 M - r0))^(3/2)/(4 π r0^3)  *)
```

The key here is to ask for a higher-order expansion than is strictly necessary.  I'm not sure why it fails with order `0`, but it's been this way (for log poles, for instance) for years. Sometimes you need to raise the order, sometimes you don't.